# RoR collection_select undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass:

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a product class that has a category. I want to insert a product without any category when not selected one.
My code

```
<% = collection_select (:product,:category_id, @categories_select,:id,:description, {:include_blank => 'Select ...'}, {id: "category", class: "form-control w-100" })%>
```

When I click Save from the following error:

> NoMethodError - undefined method `map 'for nil: NilClass:

In the terminal it shows `{"category_id" => ""}`, I want to insert NULL in the database.

Comment: When I copied the code did not come the full 'w-100' value

Comment: Try removing the parentheses there.

Comment: Do you have any callbacks in the model or controller that might interfere with the data? Your param is valid and will result with a product without a category.

Comment: In my model I have has_one: category and in my controller I have `@product = Product.new(params_product)
        @product.member_id = current_member_id
        if @product.valid?
            @product.save ...`

Comment: Just checking, but are you sure that `@categories_select` is not empty?

Comment: It has data, the page loads and shows the information but the problem is when I click save without selecting any category.

Comment: After much research I discovered that my model had problems with another table and not in the categories, but the rails gave error as if the problem were in categories and so I got lost. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.